# ArgumentNullException thrown from combobox in my custom activity

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation

I have a simple custom activity demo of WF.

The XAML code:

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="ActivityDesignerLibrary2.ActivityDesigner1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Values}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

The code behide:

```
[Designer(typeof(ActivityDesignerLibrary2.ActivityDesigner1))]
public class Class1 : CodeActivity
{
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        Values = new List<string>() { "V1", "V2", "V3"};
        Value = "V2";
    }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

When I drag this custom activity into a workflow, an error messagebox is popped up.
I found it's SelectedValue make the error, but is there anything error and how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Try to bind the Selected*Item* property of the ComboBox instead of the SelectedValue property.

Comment: @mm8, tried and a different error thrown when I try to change the selection: The argument 'value' must be of type 'System.Astivities.Presentation.Model.ModeItem', looks like a conversion issue. You know the SelectedValue way can work in my WPF desktop app, I don't know why no work in WF